# reference issue when call_user_func_array call an self-made extension function

Tags: php, reference

My php version is 5.2.17
and I made a php function

```
PHP_FUNCTION(GetProductFamily)
{
zval *productFamily;
int ret;

if(zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "z",&productFamily) == FAILURE)
{
return;
}

productFamily->value.lval = 1;
RETURN_LONG(WS_OK);
}
```

a $productFamily is passed into this function, and its value will be changed.

then in php, it is pretty ok if I just call this function:

```
<?php
$productFamily=0;
GetProductFamily(&$productFamily);
echo $productFamily;
?>
return 1;

or without &

<?php
$productFamily=0;
GetProductFamily($productFamily);
echo $productFamily;
?>
still return 1.
```

but things got strange when I use call_user_func_array to call this function

```
<?php
  $productFamily = 0;
call_user_func_array('GetProductFamily', array(&$productFamily));
echo $productFamily; //return 0, should be 1 !
?>
```

however

```
<?php
  $productFamily = 0;
call_user_func_array('GetProductFamily', array($productFamily));
echo $productFamily; //return 1 this time...
?>
```

as GetProductFamily can change the $productFamily, so I suppose we have to pass by referece here, but as you can see, the & does not work....
I´m quite confused, because when come to some basic function provided by PHP, the & is needed!

```
<?php
$array = array("ab","cd");
call_user_func_array("array_shift", array(&$array));
var_dump($array); //return array("cd");
?>
means
<?php
$array = array("ab","cd");
call_user_func_array("array_shift", array($array));
var_dump($array); //return array("ab","cd");
?>
```

why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only in internal functions the "&" is needed
when in extension, it seems the zval has done everything for you